ggsurvplot Interprets Number of Observations as Levels in newdata Argument
I am experiencing an issue with the ggsurvplot function from the survminer package in R. When attempting to plot survival curves using ggsurvplot with the newdata argument, the function incorrectly interprets the number of observations as the number of levels, resulting in an error. Without the newdata argument, the function does not recognize the levels of the factor variable correctly, leading to another error.
Observed Behavior:
With newdata Argument:
set.seed(123) 
d.dat.tot <- data.frame( 
  DONOR_SURVIVAL_TIME = rexp(100, 0.1), 
  DEAD_OR_ALIVE = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), 
  GENOTYPE.111758446 = sample(c("A/A", "G/A", "G/G"), 100, replace = TRUE) 
  ) 
# Data preparation 
d.dat.tot.clean <- d.dat.tot[d.dat.tot$DEAD_OR_ALIVE < 2, ] 
d.dat.tot.clean$GENOTYPE.111758446 <- as.factor(d.dat.tot.clean$GENOTYPE.111758446) 

cox_model_single_111758446 <- coxph(
  Surv(DONOR_SURVIVAL_TIME, DEAD_OR_ALIVE) ~ GENOTYPE.111758446, 
  data = d.dat.tot.clean
)

cox_plot_single_111758446 <- ggsurvplot(
  survfit(cox_model_single_111758446, newdata = d.dat.tot.clean),
  data = d.dat.tot.clean,
  pval = TRUE,
  conf.int = TRUE,
  risk.table = TRUE,
  legend.title = "Genotype",
  legend.labs = levels(d.dat.tot.clean$GENOTYPE.111758446),
  xlab = "Time to Last Follow-up, mo",
  ylab = "Cumulative Survival, %",
  ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
  palette = "set2"
)

This results in the error:
Error in ggsurvplot_df(d, fun = fun, color = color, palette = palette, :
The length of legend.labs should be 236.

(236 is the number of cases I have.)
Without newdata Argument:
The function fails to recognize the levels of the factor variable correctly and returns:
Error in ggsurvplot_df(d, fun = fun, color = color, palette = palette, :
The length of legend.labs should be 1.

# Sample reproducible data
set.seed(123)
d.dat.tot <- data.frame(
  DONOR_SURVIVAL_TIME = rexp(100, 0.1),
  DEAD_OR_ALIVE = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
  GENOTYPE.111758446 = sample(c("A/A", "G/A", "G/G"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

# Data preparation
d.dat.tot.clean <- d.dat.tot[d.dat.tot$DEAD_OR_ALIVE < 2, ]
d.dat.tot.clean$GENOTYPE.111758446 <- as.factor(d.dat.tot.clean$GENOTYPE.111758446)

# Cox model fitting
cox_model_single_111758446 <- coxph(Surv(DONOR_SURVIVAL_TIME, DEAD_OR_ALIVE) ~ GENOTYPE.111758446, data = d.dat.tot.clean)

# Survival curves creation
surv_fit <- survfit(cox_model_single_111758446)

# Plotting survival curves
cox_plot_single_111758446 <- ggsurvplot(
  surv_fit,
  data = d.dat.tot.clean,
  pval = TRUE,
  conf.int = TRUE,
  risk.table = TRUE,
  legend.title = "Genotype",
  legend.labs = levels(d.dat.tot.clean$GENOTYPE.111758446),
  xlab = "Time to Last Follow-up, mo",
  ylab = "Cumulative Survival, %",
  ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
  palette = "set2"
)

print(cox_plot_single_111758446)


Please use the Edit button to edit your question if you think I did not do it correctly.

I just want to plot a cox model. Very simple. But I get this strange error. I am sorry for not being used to this forum! Thank you for your help!!

Please just give your code once, you have now added a lot of the same code to the question twice.

@axeman it was not on purpose. I somehow messed it up I am very sorry.

I don't have a complete answer. I think you need to provide 1 row for newdata per group, which works for the plot, but not for the table.
sfit <- survfit(
  cox_model_single_111758446,
  newdata = data.frame(GENOTYPE.111758446 = levels(d.dat.tot.clean$GENOTYPE.111758446))
)

cox_plot_single_111758446 <- ggsurvplot(
  sfit,
  data = d.dat.tot.clean,
  pval = TRUE,
  conf.int = TRUE,
  risk.table = TRUE,
  legend.title = "Genotype",
  legend.labs = levels(d.dat.tot.clean$GENOTYPE.111758446),
  xlab = "Time to Last Follow-up, mo",
  ylab = "Cumulative Survival, %",
  ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
  palette = "set2"
)


